# Selenium iOS Driver behind Proxy

Tags: selenium, xamarin, selenium-webdriver, appium

We are trying to run some automated tests for our Xamarin based iOS app using the Selenium `IOSDriver` within Visual Studio for Mac.

The error we are getting when we run them is (I've sanitised to remove the URL we are actually trying to send the request to).

`A exception with a null response was thrown sending an HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL https://<Test Host URL>. The status of the exception was NameResolutionFailure, and the message was: nodename nor servname provided, or not known nodename nor servname provided, or not known`

Because our machines are behind a proxy we often see DNS errors like this when the code sending the request is unaware of the proxy.

We've tried various approached to setting the proxy, such as `HttpClient.DefaultProxy` and `OpenQA.Selenium.Proxy` but the error still persists.

Are there any other ways to tell Selenium that it is operating behind a proxy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else struggling with this the answer seemed to be using a 'HttpCommandExecutor'

```
        var uri = new Uri("https://hub.browserstack.com/wd/hub/");
        var commandExecutor = new HttpCommandExecutor(uri, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30))
        {
            Proxy = new WebProxy
            {
                Address = new Uri("http://your.proxy")
            }
        };

        driver = new IOSDriver<IOSElement>(commandExecutor, options);
```